# Prove or disprove the inequality with a quantifier

Tags: inequality, quantifiers

$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}, x - y^2 < 0$

Let $x = y^2 - 1$ then $y^2 - y^2 - 1 = -1 < 0$

This proof got marked wrong, why?

Comment: If $x=-5$ then what would you pick for $y$?

Comment: Say it aloud.  There exists an $x$, for all $y, x-y^2< 0$.  You must pick your $x$ first, and not let your $x$ depend on $y.$  If it was phrased $\forall y, \exists x$ that would mean something else, and you would be aloud to proceed as you did.

Answer (score 2):

The existential quantifier comes first in the statement, meaning that the chosen $x$ must work for all $y$. You defined $x$ in terms of $y$. A correct proof would be: Let $x=-1$. Then, for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x=-1<0\leq y^{2}\implies x-y^{2}<0$.

What you proved is essentially that 
$$
\forall y\in\mathbb{R},\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:x-y^{2}<0.
$$